# how i fill automatically a form on external site and get results by curl and php

Tags: php, curl

how i fill automatically a form on external site [te.eg](https://billing.te.eg/Arabic/BillInquiry.aspx) by **area code** and **Phone number** when the form is **submitted** will **redirect** to another link like `https://billing.te.eg/Arabic/BillStatus.aspx?Acc=A4002281809` i want **Extract** from html of this page (some Specified content between **span** element) like `<span id="SpanPhoneNumber" dir="ltr">02-26981106</span>` AND `<span id="SpanCurrentBalance">19.30</span>` ..

this is the form code what i want to fill it on external site

```
<td style="width:800px;vertical-align:top;">
                                 <div style="width: 95%; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 35px; margin-right: 30px;font-size:14px;">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody><tr>
                                        <td>كود المنطقة
                                        </td>
                                        <td>رقم التليفون
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                                            <div id="PinCodeLabel" style="overflow: hidden; width: 0px;">
                                                الكود السرى
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="TxtAreaCode" type="text" placeholder="كود المنطقة" style="width: 67px;" value="02" onkeyup="javascript:InquirySubmit(event);" maxlength="3" onkeydown="javascript:InquiryByTelephoneValueChanged();">
                                            <input type="hidden" id="TxtAreaCodeRegex" value="^[0-9]{1,3}$">
                                            <input type="hidden" id="TxtAreaCodeValidationEmpty" value="من فضلك ادخل كود المنطقة">
                                            <input type="hidden" id="TxtAreaCodeValidationInvalid" value="'كود المنطقة من رقم إلا ثلاثة أرقام، مثلا '02">
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="TxtPhoneNumber" type="text" placeholder="رقم التليفون" style="width: 120px;" onkeyup="javascript:InquirySubmit(event);" maxlength="8" onkeydown="javascript:InquiryByTelephoneValueChanged();">
                                            <input type="hidden" id="TxtPhoneNumberRegex" value="^[0-9]{6,8}$">
                                            <input type="hidden" id="TxtPhoneNumberValidationEmpty" value="من فضلك ادخل رقم التليفون">
                                            <input type="hidden" id="TxtPhoneNumberValidationInvalid" value="يتكون رقم التليفون من 6-8 أرقام">
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div id="PinCodeInput" style="overflow: hidden; width: 0px;">
                                                <input id="TxtPinCode" type="password" placeholder="الكود السرى" style="width: 73px;" onkeyup="javascript:InquirySubmit(event);" maxlength="4">
                                                <input type="hidden" id="TxtPinCodeRegex" value="^[0-9]{4,4}$">
                                                <input type="hidden" id="TxtPinCodeValidationEmpty" value="من فضلك ادخل الكود السرى">
                                                <input type="hidden" id="TxtPinCodeValidationInvalid" value="الكود السرى مكون من أربعة أرقام">
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                                            <div style="border: 2px solid; border-radius: 90px; height: 30px; background-color: #ee2226; box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #888888; border-color: #ee2226; padding-top: 3px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript:Inquiry();">
                                                <table>
                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                        <td style="vertical-align: top; padding-right: 5px;">
                                                            <img alt="" src="Images/InvoiceIcon.png" style="border-width: 0px"></td>
                                                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-decoration: none; color: white; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; white-space: nowrap; padding-left: 5px;">اعرض الفواتير</td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <div id="BtnShowBillsLoading" style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
                                                                <img alt="" src="Images/loading0.gif">
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody></table>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody></table>
                                 </div>
                        </td>
```

i try by this function but it's not working , don't show any result or errors

```
  function httpPost($url,$params)
    {
      $postData = '';
       //create name value pairs seperated by &
       foreach($params as $k => $v) 
       { 
          $postData .= $k . '='.$v.'&'; 
       }
       rtrim($postData, '&');

        $ch = curl_init();  

        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postData));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);    

        $output=curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
        return $output;
    }
    $params = array(
       "TxtAreaCode" => "02",
       "TxtPhoneNumber" => "26981106"
    );

    echo httpPost("https://billing.te.eg/Arabic/BillInquiry.aspx",$params);
```

Comment: the form code you posted isn't really a form.  It calls the InquirySubmit function which might use ajax to post the input field values to another page.  You have to find out the url of that page it posts to, it could be something totally different from BillInquiry.aspx, and the function could rename the variables.  Use the "network" tab on your browser's developer tools to capture and reverse engineer the ajax call, then you'll have enough info to build your curl.

Comment: also, my forms use a nonce, so I'll only accept submissions from people who first visited the form page and have javascript on.  It prevents bots from abusing my forms, and would prevent you from curling posts into my forms.  If the site is modern they'll prevent what you're trying

Comment: @RightClick thanx brother for your explanation , yeah you are right it's not html form , they use javascript in this link i think `https://billing.te.eg/Arabic/Scripts/PhoneAreaCodeInquiry.js?A=1` but how i used it with curl , that's my problem , i need An example

Comment: While you're looking at the page, press F12.  It will bring up the developer tools.  Across the top are a bunch of tabs, Elements is usually the first.  Click on the one called Network, if there is anything in there, use the clear button to clear your screen.  While you're sitting there, some requests might happen in the background, clear them.  Then when you're ready, submit the form.  You'll see your new request appear at the bottom. Click on it and go to the Headers tab.  That will show you the url it posted to, and all of the variables. Should be everything you need.

Comment: @RightClick yeah i if get the `url` with `variables` that is will help me much , but it not show like you say , in the end that is `Request URL:https://billing.te.eg/Arabic/BillStatus.aspx?Acc=A4002281809` this link i already know it , the form in this site don't send the $var in the link , you put area code + phone num in form  then redirect you to another page (Request URL) with your account code `A4002281809` in the link , i try to get info Directly from this link that's will be easy but this page don't open Directly , you must pass through by the form .

Comment: `Request URL:https://billing.te.eg/English/BillInquiry.aspx/InquiryByPhone`
`Request Method:POST` AreaCode: "02"
PhoneNumber: "26981106"
PinCode: ""

Comment: but honestly, after looking at that site, there's a lot of ajax going on there.  I think you're going to have a hell of a time scraping that, or whatever you're trying.  Anyway, this is the info you need to replicate that form with curl, did I earn an upvote? haha.  As you pointed out, it will then bring you to the account's page.  So in egypt you can look up how much your buddy owes on their phone plan by just knowing their phone number?

Comment: @RightClick , so you Advised me Leave this matter ^_^ Lol , me too I think I have reached the stage of despair .. anyway thank you very much .. For your question ,like you saw in the site you can not know the owner name of phone number, and find out how much value on this phone it's not important information , right ... i make this script for only know if this phone number is Exists or not and Works or not .

Answer (score 0):

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

If the header is the only response you want to get it, so set it true:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
```

If there is not problem then remover the header from the HTML:

```
$skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
$data= substr($data,$skip);
```

There may be redirects so set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` true:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

To get more info on the problem you need more options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

Get the curl error code if there is one:

```
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  if (curl_errno($ch)){
      $data .= 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
      echo $data;
  }
```

Otherwise get the rest of the info: `curl_getinfo()`.

```
  else {
    $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
    $responseHeader = substr($data,0,$skip);
    $data= substr($data,$skip);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $info = var_export($info,true);
   }
   echo $responseHeader . $info . $data;
```

Comment: thanks brother , but i found the right code , i must post data to form by `json` but my problem now is how i  Extract HTML content